# Perl : Store Print Outputs of a function without Changing the function

Tags: perl, file-io

I have a sub routine :

```
sub application(**arguments**)
{
      print ("found the black ship");
      # many more print statements.
      return 18000;
}
```

I need to get the data printed by the above subroutine in a file.

**PS : I cannot change the function variables, only thing I can do is accessing the function.**

Comment: Perl does not support arguments in the function definition like the way you implied here, unless you have a very recent Perl and [the `signatures` feature turned on](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Signatures).

Answer (score 2):

As you are printing to the "default file handle", and not explicitly to `STDOUT`, you can just call [`select`](http://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#select) before you call the method. There's no need to mess around with the `STDOUT` file handle.

```
my $output = '';
open my $capture, '>', \$output;
my $old_fh = select $capture;

application(...);

select $old_fh;   # restore default file handle, probably STDOUT
close $capture;
print "The output of application() was: $output\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

OK what you really want is to redirect STDOUT to a file before calling the function, then redirect it back afterwards:

```
# open filehandle log.txt
open (my $LOG, '>>', 'log.txt');

# select new filehandle
select $LOG;

application();

# restore STDOUT
select STDOUT;
```

Comment: Any other way to swap the STDOUT with File handle ? As in my current situation select will be treated as an unrecognized function as Iam working on a files which are a hybrid form of perl.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-open `STDOUT` (you need to close it first though).

```
close STDOUT;
open STDOUT, '>>', 'somefile.txt' or die $!;
application(...);
```

This is all in the documentation for [`open()`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).